# Determine the outcome of process ran via fork()/execl()

Tags: c, bash, fork

I have this code

```
# include <stdio.h> 
# include <unistd.h> 
# include <sys/wait.h> 
# include <stdlib.h> 
# include <string.h> 
# include <assert.h>

int parse( char * arg)
{ 
    int t; 
    t = fork(); 
    if (t < 0)
        return -1; 
    if (t == 0)
    {
        execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", arg,NULL); 
        exit(1);
    } 
    return t; 
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int t, tt, status, i;
    i = 1;

    for (i=1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        t = parse(argv[i]); 
        tt = wait(&status); 
        assert(tt == t);

    }
    return 0; 
}
```

that can run one or multiple commands.

I'm trying to make it stop if one of the given command failed.

Actually it keeps running even if one command failed

```
./test 'ech foo' 'echo too'
sh: 1: ech: not found
too
```

I did try multiple solutions with `wait()` and `waitpid()` but still not working.

Comment: [`WEXITSTATUS(status) != 0`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) might be of help

Comment: you could do this as a simple shell script: `try() { for cmd do eval "$cmd" || return; done; }` (`test` is a standard shell command so it is unwise to use it for another purpose.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exit status of the child process will be non-zero when the shell fails to execute a program. You can check by evaluating the `status` variable returned from the `wait()` call.

It's not so straightforward, since `wait()` packs more information into `status` than just the exit code. Additionally, the available information also changes depending on the value of `WIFCONTINUED`, `WIFEXITED`, ....

If we are interested in the fact that the child has exited successfully via the normal path, we could use:

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int t, tt, status, i;
    i = 1;

    for (i=1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        t = parse(argv[i]); 
        tt = wait(&status);
        assert(tt == t);
        if ((! WIFEXITED(status)) || (WEXITSTATUS(status) != 0)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Command '%s' failed, aborting...", argv[i]));
            return 1;
        }

    }
    return 0; 
}
```